# Why are Visual Studio Web Deploy updates so slow?

Tags: visual-studio, publishing, webdeploy

When using Visual Studio 2013 to publish a web application to a server using WebDeploy, why is it slow slow, and can this process be speeded up?

If the application is deployed from the same machine, the update speed is vastly improved as it only updates changed files.

If the application is deployed from a different machine, then *every file* is uploaded again, even if they have not changed.  I suspect VS is using primitive file time-stamp checking to determine if to update the file or not.

Issue is, with an application weighing in at 70MB, the update can take a good while.

Comment: Just stumbled on this as I'm having the same issue. Web Deploy is very slow and is far from clever in the way it chooses what files to send. On every deploy for me it's uselessly replacing files that haven't changed in months. The whole deploy process needs an overhaul, it shouldn't be this hard, and it should be a lot smarter. I was previously using git to publish, and it was super-fast and very reliable. It only deploys the actual code-delta, not even the whole file if it can avoid it.

Comment: I am getting the same problem. Different projects in the same solution act differently, some will only upload the deltas, but other projects seem to not understand the files haven't changed from the live server and want to redeploy every time. Possibly an IIS permissions ?

Comment: @dave-gbs the deploy is doing primitive timestamp checking. So if the modified datetime is different if you copy or git refresh or whatever, or the click is different by a fraction of a second, it'll think the file has changed.

Comment: @simbolo we did some more testing after this, and the problem (as you mention) does seem to be related to git commits...

Answer (score 0):

By default WebDeploy would check for changed files by comparing timestamps. In a lot of cases the timestamp might be different even when the contents of the file is identical. The `-useChecksum` flag can be used to check the contents of the file instead of the timestamp which will speed up deployments where timestamps for files are different but the contents of the files are the same, for example you can use the flag like this:

```
WebApplication1.deploy.cmd /y /M:localhost -useChecksum
```